# ANR at android.os.Handler.handleCallback: Main thread blocked

Tags: java, android, android-anr-dialog

We are facing an ANR that has no information about what's going on in the app, but happens on 8% of the devices which is **a lot**. It probably started happening after updating some libraries such as

1. Advertisement network libraries (applovin mediation with Admob),
2. Appcompat libraries (from 1.2.0 to 1.3.0, specifically `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0`),
3. Material design libraries,
4. Recyclerview (androidx, from 1.2.0 to 1.2.1)

etc...

Here is the ANR report:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Blocked
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8506)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1139)
```

That's it. Thousands of reports, just showing this. No other callbacks or traces.

Due to the lack of this stack trace (I'm pretty sure this is not the actual place the app is stuck), we have integrated a SDK called **Embrace** ([after some research I've found this link](https://blog.embrace.io/solve-application-not-responding/)), thinking that we could deduce what happens before this report actually happens. But, the SDK does not report anything like what Google reports, and we can only see reports regarding to Webview initializations. However, those were also present on the previous versions and **should not** cause anything.

The app has a foreground service that runs almost forever, and between the versions that has no ANR like this and has ANR like this, only have minor differences on the code that should not block this much. Most of them are already reverted, but the ANRs are still there.

The handler code on the last stack points to this:

```
private static void handleCallback(Message message) {
    message.callback.run();
}
```

I can't see anything that would block the main thread on this specific line such as any synchronization or something, and yet, there are almost 10k reports that the devices suffer on this specific line. Mostly affecting Android 10 and 11, but we also have reports from lower Android versions as well, that could be ignored for now.

What could be causing this? Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

If you need any other information, please let me know.

Comment: Add [ANRWatchDog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) to get the stacktrace . Then only u can do something about this . Recently i faced This [ANR](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1430) which was caused by a firebase lib, just upgrading the version fixed it .

Comment: @ADM Unfortunately we don't have a place to report ANRs in such manner. This is also not reproducable locally, we only have reports from Google at this point. Plus, the ANR report on your link clearly has a mutex held on to it, which could easily block the main thread. The problem here is that there are no mutexes or synchronizations in my case, it just blocks according to Google without anything, but I don't know how.